# How To Make Former Form Calendar Always Active (Serious Calendar Problems)

Tags: php, jquery, calendar

We have a website with a jquery form calendar. As part of the new design, we took the calendar out of the form and then we restyled it.

The previous functionality for the calendar is that the calendar shows upcoming events highlighted in blue, the user would have clicked on the form input field and the calendar would appear.

In the new design, we need the calendar with events to always be showing. We have done this however there is a problem. The problem is that for us to see the upcoming events in blue, we need to first get the calendar month and change it to next month, then back to this month.

It will not show the calendar active with events showing straight away without needing to fidgit with dates...

Any ideas.. help!

[Here is the link to the page in question.](http://www.mycityvenue.com/profile.php?id=42#) ( To see events change the month to next month then back to this month)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you get your events through ajax when the month or year changes.
You have a couple of options.

1. Trigger the same function on document ready, so your ajax call will get the events.
2. Populate a JSON object with the current month as part of the page. Then, feed that JSON to the same calendar function that populates the events from the ajax results. This way, the user doesn't have to wait for the initial month's events to arrive using ajax.

Also, you have a JS error on the page. Look at the console when you load the page and you will see the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'catcomplete'  scripts.js:127
```

**EDIT**
Solution as mentioned on comment, placed here for visibility.

```
$(function() { $('.ui-datepicker-month').trigger('change') })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response,

have you come across any online guides on how to trigger the function on document ready ?

Regards

W

Comment: You should be able to just copy the same code you run onchange and put it in $(document).ready(function(){ //here });

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Incase anyone else has this problem, here was the solution.

$(function() { $('.ui-datepicker-month').trigger('change') })